# Need to display item that have value zero in google chart

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am making web application that display google chart.I am showing items in my application.But my problem is that google chart do not display the item which have value zero.Suppose if i have 4 item a,b,c,d value 1,3,0,0 respectively then only a,b item is shown in chart.c,d are not shown.even legends are also not shown.It looks like there is only 2 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in option add sliceVisibilityThreshold:0
this allow display all values greater than 0 because if value equals or greater then threshold then chart treat it as slice, and display your item
code looks like:

var options = {sliceVisibilityThreshold:0};